# javascript - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am using webRTC for web to web calling. I got a reference from https://github.com/fycth/webrtcexample/tree/master/www. I upload it to the https server but it shows me an error in console

WebSocket connection to 'wss://myserver.com/signalling' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

please let me know how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

most probably signalling server is not on up or running state.

you can check your connection via :https://www.websocket.org/echo.html